# Subtracting a positive definite matrix from a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-definite

It is well-known that
$$\mathrm{Diag}(x)- xx^\top \succeq 0 \iff x_i \geq 0,\ i=1,\ldots,n,\ \sum_{i=1}^nx_i \leq 1, $$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mathrm{Diag}(x)$ is the diagonal matrix whose $i$-th diagonal element is $x_i$.

Let us have another variable $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_i \geq y_i \geq 0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. Obviously, if $y=x$, then we have $\mathrm{Diag}(y)- xx^\top \succeq 0$ by the equivalence above. My question is, can we say that for sure $\mathrm{Diag}(y) - xx^\top \not \succeq 0 $ if $y \neq x$?

As an attempt, I tried to see what happens when $n=2$. $\mathrm{Diag}(y) - xx^\top$ becomes:
$$\begin{pmatrix} y_1 - x_1^2  & - x_1x_2 \\ -x_1x_2 & y_2 - x_2^2  \end{pmatrix}$$
so I should show that if $y_1 < x_1$ or $y_2 < x_2$, then assuming diagonal is non-negative, I should show:
$$(y_1 - x_1^2)(y_2 - x_2^2) < (x_1x_2)^2.$$
I tried many ways, and I am unable to prove this.

Comment: If $x_1 = 1$, but the three other variables are zero, is that a counterexample?

Comment: Thanks for this counter example! I know it is too late and my question is more general, but actually I have a constraint $\sum_i y_i + 1 \geq 2 \sum_i x_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a characterization of when the matrix is positive semidefinite. Using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we find that
$$
\operatorname{diag}(y) - xx^\top \succeq 0 \iff \pmatrix{\operatorname{diag}(y) & x\\x^\top & 1} \succeq 0 \iff 1 - x^\top\operatorname{diag}(y)^{-1} x \geq 0.
$$
In particular, we find that $\operatorname{diag}(y) - xx^\top$ is positive definite if and only if
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2}{y_i} \leq 1.
$$
In the case that $y = x$, this simplifies to your result.

As written, this proof only applies to the case where the entries of $y_i$ are positive. However, we can extend this by noting that the limit of positive semidefinite matrices is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Many thanks for this nice answer. I guess the bottom right element of the Schur matrix is 1, not 0, right?

Comment: @i Right.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Suppose $x>0$ and $\sum_ix_i<1$. Then $\operatorname{diag}(x)-xx^T>0$ and hence $\operatorname{diag}(y)-xx^T>0$ when $y$ is slightly smaller than $x$.